# Handling null in java Resultset using wasnull()

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to handle null in resultset getting below mentioned error

Code:
here query returns null, in case of null versionNo should be 0

```
int versionNo = 0;
        try {
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if (res.wasNull()) {
                versionNo = 0;
            } else {
                while (res.next()) {
                    versionNo = res.getInt(1);
                }
            }
```

Error: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.wasNull(ResultSetImpl.java:2496)

Comment: @DannyFried In a correctly implemented JDBC driver, `executeQuery` will **never** return null. It will either return a - possibly empty - result set, or it will throw a `SQLException`.

Comment: The above code snippet work perfectly for hive,in case of MySQL we have to keep if condition inside the while loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MySQL Connector/J driver should not throw a `NullPointerException` in this situation, but instead should have thrown a `SQLException` that the result set is not on a row. This is a bug.

However, the [`wasNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()) method is for checking if the last **primitive** value read from the result set was `null` (as primitives don't support `null`, while a database column does):

> Reports whether the last column read had a value of SQL `NULL`. Note
>   that you must first call one of the getter methods on a column to try
>   to read its value and then call the method `wasNull` to see if the
>   value read was SQL `NULL`.

There are three problems with your code:

1. You always need to use `rs.next()` to check if there is a row (and move to that row if it exists), before you can retrieve values.
2. You need to retrieve a value (eg `getInt(1)`), before you can call `wasNull()`.
3. You use `wasNull()` to assign `0` to `versionNo`, which is entirely unnecessary because `getInt` will return `0` if the column value is `NULL` (see [`getInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)): *"Returns: the column value; if the value is SQL `NULL`, the value returned is `0`"*)

To fix your code, you need to do something like:

```
try (ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    while (res.next()) {
        versionNo = res.getInt(1);
        if (res.wasNull()) {
            // whatever you want to, other than setting versionNo to 0
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that if you have multiple rows, this will effectively return the value of the last row.

On the other hand if you want to check if there is no row, then you should do something like:

Option 1: equivalent logic

```
try (ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    if (res.next()) {
       do {
           versionNo = res.getInt(1);
       } while (res.next());
    } else {
        // no rows
    }
}
```

Option 2: initialize `versionNo` to a default value. If you are only interested in initializing `versionNo` to zero, you can also just do it before processing rows.

```
try (ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    versionNo = 0;
    while (res.next()) {
        versionNo = res.getInt(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The above code works fine with hive, for MySQL used rs.next() before applying any condition as you mentioned

Comment: @Ravikiran That would mean that Hive is not correctly implementing the JDBC specification.